# jQuery - What are differences between $(document).ready and $(window).load?

Tags: jquery

What are differences between

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 //my code here
});
```

and

```
$(window).load(function(){
  //my code here
});
```

---

And I want to make sure that:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

})
```

and

```
$(function(){

});
```

and

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

});
```

are the same.

Can you tell me what differences and similarities between them?

Comment: possible duplicate of [window.onload vs document.ready](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/window-onload-vs-document-ready)

Comment: lolz, he copied from the same link after me (without mentioning) and got accepted :P Lesson learned, don't explain to developers, they like to see code instead :D

Comment: @Rifat I'm sorry, but Oyeme's format is easier to read >_<

Comment: @eureka It's OK. You don't have to be sorry :) We both tried to help you. But, he should have mentioned the credit :P

Comment: possible duplicate of [window.onload vs. body.onload vs. document.onready](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474037/window-onload-vs-body-onload-vs-document-onready)

Answer (score 492, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // executes when HTML-Document is loaded and DOM is ready
  console.log("document is ready");
});


$(window).load(function() {
  // executes when complete page is fully loaded, including all frames, objects and images
  console.log("window is loaded");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Query 3.0 version**

#### [Breaking change: .load(), .unload(), and .error() removed](https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#breaking-change-load-unload-and-error-removed)

> These methods are shortcuts for event operations, but had several API
>   limitations. The event `.load()` method conflicted with the ajax `.load()`
>   method. The `.error()` method could not be used with `window.onerror`
>   because of the way the DOM method is defined. If you need to attach
>   events by these names, use the `.on()` method, e.g. change
>   `$("img").load(fn)` to `$(img).on("load", fn)`.<sup>[1](https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#breaking-change-load-unload-and-error-removed)</sup>

```
$(window).load(function() {});
```

Should be changed to

```
$(window).on('load', function (e) {})
```

These are all equivalent:

```
$(function(){
}); 

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
});

$(document).ready(function(){
});

$(document).on('ready', function(){
})
```

Comment: point to orignal post : http://4loc.wordpress.com/2009/04/28/documentready-vs-windowload/

Comment: The latter is preferred as the others are deprecated.  Also, the latter (I believe) specifically allows multiple handlers so you can have multiple scripts all have a .on('ready' ...) handler

Comment: `.on( "ready", handler )` - deprecated as of jQuery 1.8.
see https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: What's the difference between `$(document).ready` and `$(document).load`?

Comment: $(document).ready - "executes when HTML-Document is loaded and DOM is ready" - so it will run immediately after the document is loaded, not waiting for any pictures to load, or frames, objects or whatever is not yet loaded. 
$(document).load - "executes when complete page is fully loaded, including all frames, objects and images" - so it will wait for EVERYTHING to load - document, DOM, images, scripts, frames, objects, whatever - and then and only then will it run.

Comment: This answer should be edited to read `$(window).on('load', function() {...` to comply with jQuery 3's newer deprecation of the `.load()` method.

Answer (score 35):

`document.ready` is a jQuery event, it runs when the DOM is ready, e.g. all elements are there to be found/used, but not necessarily all the content. 
`window.onload` fires later (or at the same time in the worst/failing cases) when images and such are loaded. So, if you're using image dimensions for example, you often want to use this instead.

Also read a related question:
[Difference between $(window).load() and $(document).ready() functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584373/difference-between-window-loadfunction-and-document-readyfunction)

Answer (score 14):

These three functions are the same:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

})
```

and

```
$(function(){

});
```

and

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

});
```

here `$` is used for define `jQuery` like `$` = `jQuery`.

Now difference is that

- `$(document).ready` is jQuery event that is fired when `DOM` is loaded, so it’s fired when the document structure is ready.
- `$(window).load` event is fired after whole content is loaded like page contain images,css etc.

Answer (score 12):

From the [jQuery API Document](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

> While JavaScript provides the `load` event for executing code when a
>   page is rendered, this event does not get triggered until all assets
>   such as images have been completely received. In most cases, the
>   script can be run as soon as the DOM hierarchy has been fully
>   constructed. The handler passed to `.ready()` is guaranteed to be
>   executed after the DOM is ready, so this is usually the best place to
>   attach all other event handlers and run other jQuery code. When using
>   scripts that rely on the value of CSS style properties, it's important
>   to reference external stylesheets or embed style elements before
>   referencing the scripts.
>
> In cases where code relies on loaded assets (for example, if the
>   dimensions of an image are required), the code should be placed in a
>   handler for the `load` event instead.

---

**Answer to the second question -**

No, they are identical as long as you are not using jQuery in no conflict mode.

Answer (score 7):

The Difference between `$(document).ready()` and `$(window).load()` functions is that the code included inside `$(window).load()` will run once the entire page(images, iframes, stylesheets,etc) are loaded whereas the **document ready** event fires before all images,iframes etc. are loaded, but after the whole DOM itself is ready.

---

```
$(document).ready(function(){

})
```

and

```
$(function(){

});
```

and

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

});
```

There are not difference between the above 3 codes.

They are equivalent,but you may face conflict if any other JavaScript Frameworks uses the same dollar symbol **$** as a shortcut name.

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery.ready(function($){
 //Code using $ as alias to jQuery
});
```

Comment: Difference between jQuery(document).ready(function(){                      and                                                                                                    jQuery(document).ready(function($){  ?  Note the $ inside the parentheses .

Answer (score 5):

```
$(document).ready(function(e) { 
    // executes when HTML-Document is loaded and DOM is ready  
    console.log("page is loading now"); 
});

$(document).load(function(e) { 
    //when html page complete loaded
    console.log("completely loaded"); 
});
```

Comment: Please explain your answer as well.

Comment: Copied from https://4loc.wordpress.com/2009/04/28/documentready-vs-windowload/ (as well as the accepted answer).

Answer (score 3):

The ready event is always execute at the only html page is loaded to the browser and the functions are executed....
But the load event is executed at the time of all the page contents are loaded to the browser for the page.....
we can use $ or jQuery when we use the noconflict() method in jquery scripts...

Answer (score 1):

> **$(window).load** is an event that fires when the DOM and all the content (everything) on the page is fully loaded like CSS, images and frames. One best example is if we want to get the actual image size or to get the details of anything we use it.
>
> **$(document).ready()** indicates that code in it need to be executed once the DOM got loaded and ready to be manipulated by script. It won't wait for the images to load for executing the jQuery script.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    //$(window).load was deprecated in 1.8, and removed in jquery 3.0
    // $(window).load(function() {
    //     alert("$(window).load fired");
    // });

    $(document).ready(function() {
        alert("$(document).ready fired");
    });
</script>
```

> $(window).load fired after the $(document).ready().

```
$(document).ready(function(){

}) 
//and 
$(function(){

}); 
//and
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

});
```

> Above 3 are same, $ is the alias name of jQuery, you may face conflict if any other JavaScript Frameworks uses the same dollar symbol $. If u face conflict jQuery team provide a solution [no-conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50843445/5852550) read more.
>
> **$(window).load was deprecated in 1.8, and removed in jquery 3.0**