# document.ready vs document.onLoad

Tags: javascript, jquery, onload, document-ready

I am wondering which one is the right one to run the js code which calculates the height of vertical menu depending on the window height and sets it on time, not late, not early.

I am using `document.ready` but it is not really helping me with the issue, it is not setting sometimes, I have to reload the page, then it is working, but not on the first load.

How to solve this problem?

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     var winh = document.body.clientHeight;
     var footer = document.getElementById('footer').offsetHeight;
     document.getElementById('sidebar').style.height = winh - 5/2*footer + 'px';
     document.getElementById('sidebar').style.marginBottom = footer + 'px';

     $(window).resize(function(){
         var winh = document.body.clientHeight;
         var footer = document.getElementById('footer').offsetHeight;
         document.getElementById('sidebar').style.height = winh - 5/2*footer + 'px';
         document.getElementById('sidebar').style.marginBottom = footer + 'px';
     });
});
```

Comment: Are you resizing before the page loads? Your window.resize could be called before ready is set.

Comment: @AJak ready and resize do the same thing,

Comment: @AJak although the tabbing in the example is wrong, the resize event is being added in the `ready` function, so it can't fire before the preceding code.

Comment: **See also:** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8396407/jquery-what-are-differences-between-document-ready-and-window-load

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**ready**

When you run code when the document is ready, it means the DOM is loaded - but not things like images. If images will affect the height and width and the image tag has no width and height set, ready isn't the choice for you - otherwise it probably is.

**onload**

This includes images - so everything will be loaded. This means it fires a bit later.

**both**

```
var calculateSize = function () {
     var winh = document.body.clientHeight;
     var footer = document.getElementById('footer').offsetHeight;
     document.getElementById('sidebar').style.height = winh - 5/2*footer + 'px';
     document.getElementById('sidebar').style.marginBottom = footer + 'px';
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    calculateSize();

     $(window).resize(calculateSize);
});

window.onload = calculateSize ;
```

Comment: great, this should be the answer, let me try first :D

Comment: i put all this code in one <script> tag in head, is it okay? it seems however not to be working for the pages which have images

Comment: Any reason `$(window).resize(calculateSize)` is inside `document.ready`? Why not simply: `$(document).ready(calculateSize); $(window).on('resize load', calculateSize)`?

Comment: @JosephSilber good question. Depends if you want to listen to resizes before the DOM is ready. It's probably an edge case.