# Why we use this `Jquery(document).ready()` instead `$(document).ready()`

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Why we use this `Jquery(document).ready()` instead `$(document).ready()`

Actually this both are giving same result, but what the reason for using one of the, normally lost of people are using `$(document).ready()` instead above listed

Comment: No one use the above, unless you removed the extra dot.

Comment: `$` is an alias for `jQuery` so you can use either one.

Comment: here all things are explained in detail plz refer this link ([here][1])


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8396407/jquery-what-are-differences-between-document-ready-and-window-load

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is usually to avoid conflict with other libraries that could be using the "$" sign.

Answer (score 2):

Well you may have more JavaScript libraries than only jQuery, and some of them may use the dollar sign `$` too. If you use `jQuery` instead, you have more guaranted, that in this variable will be jQuery instance.

Answer (score 1):

This is to prevent namespace collision. The dollar sign might be used by other JavaScript libraries. For this jQuery also provides the `jquery.noConflict()` function.

Answer (score 1):

its a short hand syntax.See more at http://try.jquery.com/levels/1/sections/2

Answer (score 1):

**$ and jQuery** both point to the window.jQuery object, so they are one and the same. the reason some scripts use jQuery instead of $ is to prevent conflicts with other libraries such as prototype or different versions of jquery which both also use the $ variable.

Answer (score 1):

to get full compatibility. For example in Wordpress CMS, jquery is built in, but not using $. so it's safer to create plugins using jQuery(function($){});. Take note that $ added as a parameter so that you can use it inside the ready.