# jquery add script and it loads as soon as DOM is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, attributes

Lets say I have

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function myFunction()
{
// blah blah
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<select name="mySelect">
<option value="1"> He </option>
<option value="2"> Hi </option>
<option value="3"> Ho </option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Lets say I have js function that generates this 'select' script. How can I add to it default script that will be ran as soon as DOM is loaded with jQuery?

something like that:

```
<select name="mySelect" script="myFunction()">
<option value="1"> He </option>
<option value="2"> Hi </option>
<option value="3"> Ho </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(window).load(function() {
    // your code here
});
```

[Useful stuff here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8396407/jquery-what-are-differences-between-document-ready-and-window-load)

Comment: Cant use that, because its Yii framework and it breaks a part a lots of stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Well if your are avoiding jQuery for this then:

```
window.onload = myFunction;
```

with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(myFunction);
```

or

```
$(window).load(myFunction);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // after DOM is ready
});
$(window).load(function() {
    // after DOM including graphics ready
   // specially used for images' script
});
```

Comment: Better way to check document ready event is : 
`jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // to load dom
});`

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`window.onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onload)

like

```
<script>window.onload = myFunction</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use  **[document ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
// do here

});
```

> $( document ).ready() will only run once the page Document Object
>   Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute. Code included
>   inside $( window ).load(function() { ... }) will run once the entire
>   page (images or iframes), not just the DOM, is ready.