# Using jquery's show() after refresh

Tags: jquery, show, document-ready

I have this div in every document:

```
 <div id="header" class="hide" style="top: 0px; width: 100%; z-index: 1000;">
```

And this script (in every document too):

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#loading-header").show();

    $.ajax({
        async: true,
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/PersonsAjax/Header',
        data: {},
        success: function (data) {

            $("#loading-header").hide();

            console.debug("Is there a header? " + $("#header").size());
            $("#header").show();  // **** PROBLEM *****
        }
    });

}
```

My problem is:
I'm experiencing a very weird behaviour, two scenarios:

Scenario 1 (OK):

1. Document is ready, #header is shown
2. Click a link
3. The new document is loaded and the #header is shown

Scenario 2 (problemo):

1. Document is ready, #header is shown
2. Do a browser's refresh (using F5 key)
3. The new document is loaded but the #header is not always shown.

My first thought was: *"the document is still loading, and maybe there isn't a #header yet"*, but my console.debug proved that this wasn't the problem

What is happening?
Is there a well known problem with jQuery's show() and doing refresh?
Please notice also that I'm preventing ajax calls to be cached. I double checked the ajax response and it brings the correct data

Comment: Have you tried to wrap the show in a timeout to see if it's a loading conflict? `setTimeout (function () { $(divToShow).show(); },2000);` if it does its a Dom content issue most likely. Also I believe ajax has a `done()` funtion which this should be where you at the show.

Comment: I tried to prove that it is not a dom-loading issue by doing that "console.debug". If I find out that it is a loading issue, what can I do? because that timeout isn't very elegant as a final solution. Also I should mention that doing $("#header").show() in the console after a while does indeed display the header.

Comment: Ok so it's a loading issue. So what you should do is add the done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `$(window).load(function() {});` instead of `$(document).ready(function (){});`, in this instance.

```
  $(window).load(function() {
     $("#loading-header").show();

        $.ajax({
            async: true,
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/PersonsAjax/Header',
            data: {},
            success: function (data) {

                $("#loading-header").hide();

                console.debug("Is there a header? " + $("#header").size());
                $("#header").show();  // **** PROBLEM *****
            }


    });
});
```

Comment: whats the difference between $(window).load and $(document).load?

Comment: well I answer myself with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8396407/jquery-what-are-differences-between-document-ready-and-window-load, it sounds to be the answer, let me try and mark as accepted if it works.

Comment: It did work, sorry the delay on accepting the answer. Now I'm still curious about when should I use $(document).ready vs $(window).load. I do understand the difference between them, though is not easy to say which one should I use in other scenarios

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#loading-header").show();

    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url: '/PersonsAjax/Header',
        success: function (data) {
            $("#loading-header").hide();
            //console.debug("Is there a header? " + $("#header").size());
        }
      }).done(showHeader());
    });
    //add a looping function to check for header
    function showHeader(){
         var TO = 0;
         var header = document.getElementById('header');
         if(header){
           header.style.display="block";
         }else if( TO < 10 ){
           setTimeout(showHeader,100);
           TO++;
         }else{
          console.log("showHeader Timed out");
         }
     }
```

Ajax has a done function because onsuccess is only being requested from the httpResponse and not actually done. See how they wrote it [Here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#example-1) in the jQuery Ajax API Documentation.

You can try that with the loop

Comment: I did some "refresh" tests and it still happends that sometimes the #header is shown and sometimes is not shown. It appears to have improved the "shown rate" though.

Comment: I've updated with a looping function but it does have a timeout as to not create an infinite loop.