# Hide DIV until page loads using visibility property

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a `DIV` (.`container`) and a `button` (.`btn`) which i want to hide until the page is fully loaded.I managed to do it by using dispay:none on a small `jquery` snippet, but it would be better if i could use visibillity:hidden because the page wouldnt shift (like it does with display:`none`).

basically, I have:

```
<style>
    .container {visibility:hidden;}
    .btn {visibility:hidden;}
</style
```

Is there any nice soul that could help me with `jquery` part so it only shows once the page is fully loaded?

Comment: `$(window).load(function() { // code here });` or you can do `window.onload = function() { // code here }`

Comment: A good refresher on the difference between `$(window).load()` and `$(document).ready()` functions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8396407/jquery-what-are-differences-between-document-ready-and-window-load.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is what you need to do

```
$(window).load(function() { 
    $('.container').css('visibility','visible');
    $('.btn').css('visibility','visible');
});
```

OR you could just add a class to the the container as well

```
$(window).load(function() { 
    $('.container').addClass("show");
});
```

and then for your css

```
.container.show { visibility: visible; }
.container.show .btn { visibility:visible; }
```

You can create a class just for visibility but make sure it is after the other rules so it will overwrite it. Like so

```
.container {visibility:hidden;}
.btn {visibility:hidden;}

.my_class { visibility: visible; }
```

The jquery in this case would be

```
$(window).load(function() { 
    $('.container').addClass("my_class");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

Javascript:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('.container, .btn').addClass('visible');
});
```

CSS:

```
.visible { visibility: visible; }
```

Hope help you!

Answer (score 0):

Don't overthink it! :)

```
$(function() {
    $('.container').show(); // show .container and .btn
    $('.btn').show();
});
```

Comment: This uses the display:none and then removes it which he does not want

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $(".container).show( "fast" );
}
```