# jQuery Change HTML Parameters on Page Load

Tags: jquery, html, parameters, load

When a page loads, how can I change a specific HTML element's parameters using jQuery? For example, in the following HTML, I would like to change type="submit" to type="button" and src="image1.jpg" to src="image2.jpg"

```
<form class="edit" action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="firstName">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="thisOne">
</form>
<img src="image1.jpg">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('input[name=firstName]').attr('type', 'button');
    $('img').attr('src', 'image2.jpg');
});
```

Just one example.

Comment: Instead of $(window).load, what would be the difference of using 
$(document).ready?

Comment: document.ready fires up when HTML-Document is loaded and DOM is read

Comment: while .load executes when complete page is fully loaded, including all frames, objects and images

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8396407/jquery-what-are-differences-between-document-ready-and-window-load