# Why does my page fire "ready" event in Chrome during refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, dom

I have an HTML like this:

```
<!-- simulate a slow-loading request -->
<script src="http://example.com:81/non-existent-script.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() { alert("ready"); })
</script>
```

(see http://jsfiddle.net/mK63F/)

When I open the page in Chrome, the `example.com` request should hang - but then, when I hit F5, the "ready" alert appears, *before* the page refreshes. Why does that happen? And how to distinguish that situation (i.e. refresh during page load) from "normal" page ready?

Comment: Er, maybe I'm not understanding exactly, but a refresh is just reloading the page -- so it'll become `ready` in the same way as a "normal" page load. Right?

Comment: I meant `ready` happens *before* the page refreshes. I'll edit my question.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/window-onload-vs-document-ready

Answer (score 2):

When you click `f5` browser stops all active requests and `ready` function is ruining Because everything is loaded ...

alternative is

```
$( window ).load(function() {
  alert("loaded");
});
```

---

**http://jsfiddle.net/26x2K/4/**

---

### [**LINK HERE**](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

`.load` not running if all request dont get the success responce

> #### [Also Read - jquery what are differences between document ready and window load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8396407/jquery-what-are-differences-between-document-ready-and-window-load)

Answer (score 1):

When you hit F5 for reload the request gets canceld. You can see this in devtools with status canceld:

[image]

Therefore the document is ready because no requests are loading anymore.