# Zeroclipboard and jQuery .load

Tags: php, jquery, load, zeroclipboard

so, I have a script like this

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#lista').load('gifs/1.php').fadeTo( "slow" , 1);
});
</script>

<script src="arqs/main.js"></script>
<ul id="lista"></ul>
```

main.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var DOMarr=$('#lista li').map(function(){return this;});
   var clip = new ZeroClipboard(DOMarr); 
})
```

the problem is, zeroclipboard is not "injecting" the flash file when I use .load(), if I use php include it works normally but when I switch to load it does that :(
does someone knows a workaround?

I'll need to use load to switch the list, and I'd like zeroclipboard to allow copying from the new list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.load` is an asychronous call so `.ready` may be executed before. Make sure the list is loaded before doing the ZeroClipboard call.

Comment: sorry, i didn't understand, isn't $(document).ready doing that?

Comment: .ready is called when the DOM has loaded, use .load http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8396407/jquery-what-are-differences-between-document-ready-and-window-load

Comment: ok, that worked, but then when I change the list it doesn't work anymore :(

Comment: ok so I used the same function of window.load (to inject the flash etc) for everytime I click a button to go to the next list, and it workedddddddddd.. thank youuuuuuuuuuu

Comment: one question at a time :) post the whole code or a jsfiddle and I'll look into it