# Combining a jquery slider with a jquery timed fade in

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider, delay

I have two scripts that work great independently, and now I want to combine them.
The first one is a slider that can load any content.

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#slides').slides({
        preload: true,
        preloadImage: 'img/loading.gif',
        play: 10000,
        pause: 100000,
        hoverPause: true,
        effect: 'fade',
        slidesLoaded: function() {
            $('.caption').animate({
                bottom:0
            },200);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

The second one is a script that can display a couple of div's with a smooth timed fade in.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(window).load(function(){
    $('.square').fadeTo(0,0).each(function(index) {
      var dif = index % 5;
      var lambda = parseInt(index / 8);
      $(this).delay(250 * (dif + lambda)).css('visibility','visible').fadeTo(500,1)
    });
  });
</script>
```

When the page loads, different images in div's are fading in one by one. (second script). All this is in a slider div that is activated by the first script. When the slider goes to the next slide, the second script is already activated because the document was ready. I would like it to be "reset" when the second slide is activated. Then the second slide will show the second batch of images smoothly fading in, one-by-one.

Comment: You're doing a big mistake embedding `$(document).ready()` within `$(window).load()`, read why here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8396407/jquery-what-are-differences-between-document-ready-and-window-load)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie IMHO a jQuery developer must avoid that behaviour.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie well, as you like :) IMHO that's a relevant issue a jQuery developer won't never make.

Comment: $(document).ready() removed. Now back to the issue at hand... Is it possible to make the div.square visibility hidden again, when the second slide is about to appear? By the way, here is an URL to see what we are talking about... http://freehand.nl/hamptonbay/index2.php

Comment: @user3797701: It would be nice for you to provide a JSFiddle or SO Code Snippet so that any solution can be tested :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cuLx3c46/

Comment: In the fiddle you can see that the first slide of images is fading in one by one. In the second batch, they all appear simultaneously.