# jQuery script only fires after browser resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize

I wrote a jQuery script which keeps two images side by the same height. It needs to work on document load and document resize as the images are responsive.

I thought this woas the best solution (code below), but it only works when I resize the browser?

```
function projectRowHeight() {
    var rowHeight = $('#projects').find('.col-33 img').height();
  $('#projects').find('.row').css('height', rowHeight);
}

$(document).ready(projectRowHeight);
$(window).resize(projectRowHeight);
```

Comment: have you tried... <body onload="projectRowHeight()" onresize="projectRowHeight()">

Comment: Or `$(window).load(projectRowHeight);` as in docs.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(window).load(projectRowHeight);`

Comment: Do you have an explanation for why it doesn't work in `ready()`?

Comment: @Barmar I looked through [docs](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) and still not sure: will `$(document).load` fire at the same time as `$(window).load`?

Comment: Maybe this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8396407/jquery-what-are-differences-between-document-ready-and-window-load

Comment: @Barmar Because with `document.ready` image dimensions are not resolved in time.

Comment: @dfsq I suppose Barmar knows the difference :) The problem is that there is no explanation in answer.