# Wait for image added to CSS to load - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

I have an image and I want to draw on it. To do that, I use jQuery to hide the image:

```
$("img").hide();
```

And then I create a canvas and put it in the same div with id `drawing` in the html. I then set the background of the canvas to be the same as the img src for the image I hid. This makes it look like an image but now it is actually a canvas with the image as it's background. I do this by:

```
$('#drawing > canvas').css('background-image','url('+$(".image img").attr('src')+')');
context.canvas.width = $("img").width();
context.canvas.height = $("img").height();
```

The issue I am having is that sometimes, the image isn't displayed in the canvas and the canvas is not the size of the image. I think it's probably because of some loading issue. How can I wait for the canvas to have the image displayed in the background for sure? Thank you

Edit: Note that in the DOM, the canvas always has the right src. It just doesn't display it

Edit 2: Here's the JSfiddle. Here, everything seems fine but I have a lot more going on in my code including fetching stuff from the server so it's slower there. Hope this helps you guys to understand the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/wL3ezLke/2/
Thanks again

Comment: `$(".image img")` and `$("img")` would be Array like Objects of images. You have to get a single `src`, `width`, and `height`. Use the `$(selector).each()` method, or be more specific with your jQuery.

Comment: Wild guess, because "the image isn't displayed in the canvas and the canvas is not the size of the image" -> instead document.ready, use window.load function. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8396407/jquery-what-are-differences-between-document-ready-and-window-load

Comment: @PHPglue I do not agree, we cannot know for sure here that there are more than one `.image` css class used. I do agree however that he should indeed use better jquery selectors to ensure the code won't be broken while adding other `.image` elements.

Comment: @nevermind I tried that. But that loads the image, not the one on my canvas background

Comment: @PHPglue I only have one image class and one image shown at a time. I can go to another image in which case the server will fetch it, the page will be refreshed, script will be loaded and then i will call the function to replace the image with the canvas.

Comment: Try setting the `height` and `width` before setting the background.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use:

```
$(function(){
  // Code executed once the DOM is loaded.
});
```

Official documentation:
https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: this whole code is inside a function that is called in `$(document).ready(function(){...`

Comment: I have added it. Sorry it took a while

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your problem is knowing when the image loaded (from what you describe it could be a lot of other problems though).

To test if an image has loaded it's pretty simple.

```
 var $img = $('#hiddenImg');
 if ($img[0].complete) doCanvasStuff();
 else {
      $img.on('load', function(e) {
         var $canvas = $('#drawCanvas');
          $canvas.css({width: $img.width(), height: $img.height()});
          //you can go ahead with the background image, but this is preferable
          var ctx = $canvas[0].getContext("2d");     
          ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
      }
  }
```

This should make sure you canvas loads an image only after it was loaded, or do canvas stuff right away if image was loaded, [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wL3ezLke/4/)

Comment: I don't know why but this doesn't add anything to the canvas for me. It just puts the image there and a canvas that's empty.

Comment: Make sure you set the dimensions before calling drawContext: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wL3ezLke/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$('#drawing > canvas').css('background-image','url('+$(".image img").attr('src')+')');
context.canvas.width = $("img").width();
context.canvas.height = $("img").height();
```

to

```
 context.canvas.width = $("img").width();
 context.canvas.height = $("img").height();
 $('#drawing > canvas').css('background-image','url('+$(".image img").attr('src')+')');
```

so the `height` and `width` are set before the image goes into the background.