# Whats is the difference between these document ready types? When to use them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, domdocument

I have been looking around a bit and haven't really been able to find something that says when is best to use these document ready types. The main one i use is `$(document).ready(function() {` because the syntax is clean and easy to read for me but is there an advantage of using this or not using this over the following?

Example 1:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

Example 2:

```
(function($) { 
    // code here
  $(function() {
    // code here
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Example 3:

```
$(window).load(function(){  
     //code here 
});
```

Example 4:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function(){
```

Example 5:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    //code here
});
```

Example 6:

```
$(function(){
```

I know there are a few questions on here about this but mine is asking for examples of when to actually use these and how it will benefit from the others to use it?

Comment: jQuery API docs would be good place to look maybe?  http://api.jquery.com/ready/ `$` is simply an alias for `jQuery`

Comment: 1,2,4,5,6 are all the same (with respect to when the `// code here` is executed), just with different variable names and/or shortcuts.

Comment: They all do the same thing. Example 2 is redundant unless there exists a variable `$` in the scope that you called it. `$` by default is just a shorthand for the global object `jQuery`. window load and document ready however are different **events**.

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst _3_  is `load` and not `ready`

Comment: Yes, i looked at that. It explains them vaguely but does not say when it is best to use them against using the others. My question was "when to actually use these and how it will benefit from the others"?

Comment: I understant that $ is just shorthand for calling jQuery but is there any advantage of using say jQuery(document).ready( function(){ over $(document).ready( function(){. Would there ever be a need to use jQuery(document).ready( function(){ or a situation that i would need to use this in? I can get around fine in most cases using $(document).ready( function(){ but i don't know if i could be using one of the others in situations to IMPROVE my coding skills?

Comment: @Epik would use `jQuery` in `noConflict()` situations. There is no other benefit...is the same function when `$` is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand ready(), you need to know about `DOMContentLoaded` event.

The `DOMContentLoaded` event is fired when the document has been completely downloaded and parsed, all the external scripts and internal scripts are downloaded and executed and DOM is ready to start manipulating. This event will not  wait for stylesheets, images, and subframes to finish loading. There's a `load` event which can be used to detect a fully-loaded page.

As you can see [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=domcontentloaded) `DomContentLoaded` event is supported by almost all browsers except below < IE9. There're events like `readystatechange` which can be used to emulate `DOMContentLoaded` in IE8 and in IE7, we need to call doScroll() and see if throws an exception, it will not throw any exception once DOM is loaded.

Instead of you worrying about these cross-browser differences, `ready()` in jQuery abstracts the functionality to pass callback to invoke on `DOMContentLoaded` event.

DOMContentLoaded event started at FF and later adopted by all main stream browsers like Chrome, Opera and IE but standardised in HTML5. This event will fire only in case of documents where as `load` will be triggered on successful loading of any resource like `<script> <img>`. Now know that we know that there's a gap between `DOMContentLoaded` and `load` events, many people use this event's callback to do some javascript initilization while other resources are being loaded.

You can even see these events with tools like DeveloperTools in Chrome

[image: browser events]

Example 2 and Example 1 are both same in terms of their functionality-used to pass a callback for `DOMContentLoaded`, except that in 2nd one, you're passing jQuery as argument but reading it as $, so all the functions inside that function expression can work with $ and you can still have some other library outside using $ as global object with its own functions, that way conflict between two libraries using same $ as global object is resolved.

Example 1 & 4 are same but with minor difference of using $ or jQuery as global object, some other library might be using $ for their code but it's highly unlikely that jQuery is used as global object in some other library (For Example, AngularJS has its own global object `angular` )

Example 5 is again using jQuery on the outside and $ in the function callback. So once again namespace conflicts with $ are resolved.

Hope this gives some insight :)

Answer (score 0):

All are exactly the same apart from 3.

From [jQuery - What are differences between $(document).ready and $(window).load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8396407/jquery-what-are-differences-between-document-ready-and-window-load)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 // executes when HTML-Document is loaded and DOM is ready
 alert("document is ready");
});


$(window).load(function() {
 // executes when complete page is fully loaded, including all frames, objects and images
 alert("window is loaded");
});
```