# I have the JS function that is invoked every 3 minutes by setInterval - how can I invoke it when page loads too?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following script:

```
    var results;
var cursor = 0;

function myFunction () {
    $.getJSON('list.php', function(json) {
        results = json.result;
        cursor = 0;

        // Now start printing
        printNext();
    });
}

function printNext(){
    if(cursor == results.length){
        // Reset the cursor back to the beginning.
        cursor = 0;
    }

    // Print the key1 in the div.
    //$('#device-content-user-text').html(results[cursor].key1);
    $('#device-content-user-text').hide('fast', function(){ $('#device-content-user-text').html(results[cursor].key1); $('#device-content-user-text').show('fast'); });

    // Set a delay for the current item to stay
    // Delay is key2 * 1000 seconds
    setTimeout(function(){
        printNext();
    }, results[cursor].key2 * 1000);

    // Advance the cursor.
    cursor++;
}

var interval = setInterval(function () { 
    myFunction(); 
}, 300000);  //make sql query every 5 minutes
```

and it gets the JSON string from the page list.php and prints the results one by one in a `#device-content-user-text` div. It is done every five minutes and the timer starts counting time when the user loads the page. How can I invoke this function also on the page load (and then normally every 5 minutes)?
Thanks

Comment: Your `setInterval` just calls `myFunction()` so just call `myFunction()` outside interval.

Comment: You could just call it on document ready: `$(myFunction);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [document.ready()](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var interval = setInterval(function () { 
        myFunction(); 
    }, 300000);  //make sql query every 5 minutes
    myFunction();
});
```

Also, if your just calling myFunction inside the anonymous function of setInterval, just pass the function reference itself

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var interval = setInterval(myFunction, 300000); //make sql query every 5 minutes
        myFunction();
    });
```

**Update**

Depending on what you meant by page 'load', there can be a world of difference between `document.ready` and [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/). If you want to be absolutely sure **everything** is loaded(including frames, images, etc..) then do

```
$(window).load(function() {
            var interval = setInterval(myFunction, 300000); 
            myFunction();
        });
```

Otherwise, if it is sufficient that the `DOM` is ready, just stick with `document.ready()`

See [jQuery - What are differences between $(document).ready and $(window).load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8396407/jquery-what-are-differences-between-document-ready-and-window-load)

Comment: As a side note, there is a huge difference between document ready event and `page loads` but i guess it would work here

Comment: @A.Wolff, no wait, looking it up :)

Comment: ahh http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8396407/jquery-what-are-differences-between-document-ready-and-window-load

Comment: Seeing logic of OP used code, the ready event would just be enough ;)

Comment: @A.Wolff, still, I find it useful to pay attention to the finer points. Thanks so much for your awesome tip! Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
 //Document ready
   $(function(){

        //call function
        myFunction();

       //put your interval here

    });
```