# Having trouble getting jquery-final-countdown to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to implement a modern countdown timer into my website, and I've found this one works very nicely, but after downloading it off of Github I'm having trouble getting it to work! What am I doing wrong?

https://github.com/PragmaticMates/jquery-final-countdown

This is the link to their GitHub, I downloaded the 'demo' folder and opened both the html files, but the countdown won't just start!

Here is my result: http://infntest.altervista.org/countdown/data-attributes.html

This is the tutorial, it's got the whole code: http://goo.gl/D4a9c9

My `head` tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/demo.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-countdown/2.0.1/jquery.countdown.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please post the code directly in your post not just link to a repository. Also, what doesn't work? What have you tried in terms of debugging?

Comment: Alright, posting the code, by the way, the issue is that the timer will just show 00s and not the countdown @wahwahwah

Comment: You have a 404 error so the plugin script doesn't load

Comment: check the directory of the URL that you embedded to your html if its pointing to the right path where you put the countdown script

Comment: @Jake - if you inspect the console, you'll immediately see (as NextLocal pointed out) that the js file isn't loading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `jquery-countdown.js` file is pointing to the wrong location.
Specifically, change this part:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.final-countdown.js"></script>
```

Here are all of the Javascript libraries required to run: (not counting css)

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/kineticjs/5.2.0/kinetic.min.js"></script>
<script src="//final-countdown.pragmaticmates.com/jquery.final-countdown.js"></script>
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/hurofi/edit?output)**

**[Source Code](http://pastebin.com/et3CP5Kz)**

Comment: I deem by doing this, its the most efficient way of handling sources in your javascript, hosting it from the primary webserver can slow things down a bit

Comment: It's also worth noting that if the OP had inspected the console it would have been immediately evident what the issue was...

Comment: you mean my kinetic.js file? @NextLocal

Comment: Just like my good friend wahwahwah pointed out, the developers console can be reached by pressing ````Ctrl+Shift+J```` then going to the Console tab. It's a life saver!

Comment: Ok, great, thank you guys! So what should I basically edit, the script path for the js file?

Comment: @Jake - see revised answer. Let us know if you still need any help

Comment: Yes, still won't work, edited my question with my head tag

Comment: @Jake Now your jquery just needs to come before it in the head tag. Good luck!

Comment: Dude, please forgive me, I remember I have to get the JQuery tag before any js using it, but now how many scripts tag should I implement?

Comment: Man, forgive my bad memory (really bad though) @NextLocal

Comment: @Jake You also will need kinetic before that tag. And I revised my answer again, since I accidentally referenced some other similar countdown script. Now it should work for you

Comment: `<script src="js/kinetic.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/hilios/jQuery.countdown/2.1.0/dist/jquery.countdown.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Where's the issue? D: @NextLocal You wish you never met me ahah

Comment: @Jake if you update your altervista so your head has all the scripts at the bottom of my answer (it was revised again) it should work, if not tell me and I will look at it. But right now your site still has the old code. Basically as long as jquery is above what you pasted though it should be good

Comment: Wanna move on chat? @NextLocal

Comment: 'cause I've modified my head tag, but it won't start anyways

Comment: @Jake update your site so I can see what it looks like updated, because it's still the same to me

Comment: Done, it was in a parallel link, there you go

Comment: For whatever reason the javascript file I linked wasn't the right one either. Sorry. This one is: ````<script src="//final-countdown.pragmaticmates.com/jquery.final-countdown.js"></script>```` Now remember to delete the old ````<script>```` tags at the bottom of your page and wrap your ````final_countdown()```` call in a ````$(document).ready(){..}```` block. Taking the dog for a walk, lemme know!

Comment: Thanks for the correction, but I don't know where to write that Js (and what to write inside that wrap).. such a shame >.<

Comment: Such as you helped me really a lot so far.. whenever you find some free time from here til tomorrow I'd like to see how this all ends.. Thank you again!

Comment: @Jake just see the updated answer, those are the scripts you should have and in that order. Anywhere before your ````final_countdown()```` call  should suffice, ideally in the head element. Delete any leftover old scripts at the bottom.

Comment: As it stands all you need to do is put this above the other scripts in your head: ````<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>```` and get rid of the old scripts at the bottom of the page.

Comment: I guess you need to see my file system in the backend to see each file's name, that's 'cause I think part of the code might have changed some names of some js files. You able to make a chat? I cannot do that yet @NextLocal

Comment: @Jake Here's a demo without using your server: http://jsbin.com/hurofi/edit?output

Comment: Copy the entire code from here and use this as a starting point: http://pastebin.com/et3CP5Kz Glad to hear you got it working man, cheers!

Comment: Hey dude, just a last little question, I tried to implement it (not the background, just the countdown) inside a div, but it's not working, and it says `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).final_countdown is not a function` any ideas?

Comment: @Jake now you're executing it before the html div exists. Just move ````<script src="assets/js/kinetic.js"></script>```` down to the bottom of your page. Also you're including jquery twice, I'd replace the ````<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>```` at the top of your page with ````<script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>```` and then get rid of the ````jquery.min.js```` at the bottom

Comment: Shouldn't the tags be in the head? @NextLocal

Comment: Loading CSS and JS in the head is useful because it will start loading external resources faster. But in this case it doesn't matter, anywhere in the html will be fine, you just have to understand that there is a certain order things have to happen in, and in this case your ````final_countdown()```` has to happen at the bottom of the page. (After countdown div) The ideal way to do it wouldn't be to load another ````<script src="kinetic.js">```` tag, but instead inline your code like this: ````<script>$('.countdown').final_countdown();</script>```` somewhere at the bottom before ````</html>````

Comment: Another way to get your existing code working would be changing ````$(document).ready```` to  ````$(window).load```` - the latter will wait until your page is done to run your script. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8396407/jquery-what-are-differences-between-document-ready-and-window-load

Comment: All you need to understand is that the reason previousMeetings.html isn't working is because the final_countdown function is being called before you even have a ````<div class="countdown"````

Comment: Personally how I would fix it is get rid of ````<script src="assets/js/kinetic.js"></script>```` since you don't need to load an external script just for a small bit of code. Just inline it at the bottom before ````</html>````: this code: ````<script>$('.countdown').final_countdown();</script>````

Comment: I did it, still not working, I'm sorry about that but can't understand what should be changed, maybe let's just review the head as I've already placed that line of code at the bottom (?) @NextLocal You my hero you know yeah?

Comment: Now you have jquery included in there three times. All I had to do to make it work was remove the two ````<script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>````

Comment: Were those 2 links 1 at the bottom and 1 above?

Comment: You still have a ````<script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>```` in there. Get rid of it

Comment: Awesome, now I'll try to make it responsive! Whenever you get back up and feel rested I'd like at least to share to you this other question of mine, feel free to join such as not to, you've already a lot to me, thanks @NextLocal

Comment: If you're designing something from scratch, just design everything with percents for the width. Then it'll be responsive automatically

Comment: Mh, well if you check the question I guess the main class/id is wrong 'cause it's set in px, isn't it?

Comment: I mean, it shouldn't be set in pixels

Comment: @NextLocal what if I wanna set the time of `now` and `start` to the current one, so that it doesn't restart everytime I refresh the page? I've the Js code, but where do I insert it in? `Math.round(new Date().getTime()/1000.0)`

Comment: @Jake Countdown from Nov 1 to 30 days after. http://jsbin.com/hurofi/6/edit?js,output

Comment: @NextLocal What if I can just set the end date? Like the start and the now are the same

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you aren't using the same call signature.

Their example has this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.countdown').final_countdown({
                'start': 1362139200,
                'end': 1388461320,
                'now': 1387461319
        }, function() {
                // Finish Callback
        });
});
```

Note the Finish Callback

Comment: Astute observation, but the second parameter is optional, as callbacks usually are. Source: http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/documentation.html#introduction

Comment: @Paurian, yeah the code in the tutorial is slightly different from the one on github, and now I copied the one in github, but the tutorial is a short version so it might be helpful to understand it faster

Comment: Thanks @NextLocal for pointing that out. I also tried a few variants of the URL that Jake used for jquery-countdown.js, confirming that the file isn't in the path referenced in his code (nor in other possibly misconstrued paths on his server).