# Jquery .click triggering on body load

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

On body load, the button click is triggered. This behavior is unwanted. What is causing the function to trigger?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
  <body onload="init()">
    <div class="btn"><button type="button" class="btn" id="reset" style="font-size:60px;">Reset</button></div>
    <script>
      function init() {
      $("#reset").click(sendStatus());
    }

    // FUNCTIONS 
    function sendStatus (){
      console.log("foo");
      }
    </script>  
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's because you're passing the *result* of the function to the handler, not the *reference* of the function. Try `$("#reset").click(sendStatus);`. You should also place your code in a `$(document).ready(fn)` block instead of using an outdated `onload` attribute.

Comment: That was very helpful - thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have a click event within the init function. You are calling that function within the onload attribute in the body tag.

Answer (score 0):

There are few fundamental issues with your code.

1. There is no document.ready function. Please use this instead of onload. Refer the below links to know the difference.

[window.onload vs $(document).ready()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/window-onload-vs-document-ready)

[jQuery - What are differences between $(document).ready and $(window).load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8396407/jquery-what-are-differences-between-document-ready-and-window-load)

2. In init function button click event, you are calling the function "sendStatus" instead of assigning it. Hence it is getting triggered immediately

I have modified the code as follows

```
 $(function() {

   function init() {
     $("#reset").click(sendStatus);
   }

   // FUNCTIONS 
   function sendStatus() {
     console.log("foo");
   }

     init();

 });
```

and here is the fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/7nt4q6yt/1/