# jquery calculations as per selected dropdown value loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

Iam trying to do a calculation. When a user selects a dropdown currency. The system calculates and converts the selected currency from the dropdown to INR currency values. The records are coming from mysql db and the record count will be from one record to 300 records. Here the user needs to change each currency from the drop down and the system converts this selected currency value to INR value. Its really a hectic task. So If the user changes one currency value from dropdown, the system should change the entire row currency value to the selected dropdown value and the system should calculate on certain formulae to change the value to INR. All these is working fine.

Now the issue iam facing is to implement the formulae to the jquery.

Here is the fiddle what i have done:

#### [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3zha7q5d/)

If you can check the fiddle in the jquery part i have used a formula

```
 var newTotal = currency==="INR" ? totalINR : (totalINR * conversionRate / row.find('.inrvalue').val()).toFixed(3);
```

This above formula wrong:

The actual formula iam looking at is

```
if (currency==="INR")
        {
            var newTotal = totalINR; 
        } else if (currency==="USD")
        {
            var newTotal = (row.find('.total1.').val() *  row.find('.inrvalue').val());
        } else {
            var newTotal = ((row.find('.inrvalue').val() / conversionRate) * row.find('.total1.').val());
        }
```

How will i change the existing formulae to this? When i implement this formula, iam getting an error Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .. Help Appreciated

Comment: Did i complicate the question?

Comment: what's wrong with the old formula?

Comment: Instead of the old formula, i need to implement this formula. The old formula calculation is wrong. The new formule which i would implement is as follows: if (currency==="INR")
  {
   var newTotal = totalINR; 
  } else if (currency==="USD")
  {
   var newTotal = (row.find('.total1.').val() *  row.find('.inrvalue').val());
  } else {
   var newTotal = ((row.find('.inrvalue').val() / conversionRate) * row.find('.total1.').val());
  }

Comment: i just want to know of the syntax is correct?

Comment: i have edited the question with the formulae i want

Comment: Anyone to guide me on this?

Comment: Haven't looked at all the details, but `var newTotal` should be declared outside the if blocks: https://jsfiddle.net/3zha7q5d/1/

Comment: Thank you ,but there was some more issues with the syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your function is almost right, you have only one "extra" dot after "total1"

you can safely change

```
 var newTotal = currency==="INR" ? totalINR : (totalINR * conversionRate / row.find('.inrvalue').val()).toFixed(3);
```

for

```
var newTotal = 0;
        if (currency==="INR")
        {
            newTotal = totalINR; 
        } else if (currency==="USD")
        {
            newTotal = (row.find('.total1').val() *  row.find('.inrvalue').val());
        } else {
            newTotal = ((row.find('.inrvalue').val() / conversionRate) * row.find('.total1').val());
        }
```

hope this helps

Comment: Yes it works fine..Thank you. Last question. How will i make newTotal to 3 decimals?

Comment: using the same ".toFixed(3)" you were using :)