# Execute javascript while iframe loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have a set of control variables for my iframe history. It changes after the iframe is fully loaded (when the user clic on some link inside the iframe)

```
$('#iframe').load(function(){
    if ((action == 'forward')) {
        window.historyControl+=1;
    } else {
        window.historyControl-=1;
    }
});
```

For what I'm trying to do, it works fine BUT when the user changes the iframe url BEFORE the iframe fully load then the `.load()` function doesn't execute.

The same happens if I put that inside vanilla javascript and call the function with the `onLoad=()` parameters in the iframe.

Is there a way to execute some javascript code while the iframe load his contents?

I have no control over the iframe contents.

Comment: Remove the load/onload handler??

Comment: You are listening the loading event from the iframe element, not for the content of the iframe.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude to which iframe event should I listen to then?

Comment: @Jonasw I didn't quite understand your idea.

Comment: You must to access iframe content (if you are not violating the cross-origin security layer) and listen to that content load.

Comment: I'm opening a PHP file that works like a proxy opening a third party website. I can put things in this PHP if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the trace of @MarcosPérezGude, I added an script on top of the `<head>` in the iframe's php file. It triggers a function

```
<script>window.parent.myFunction();</script>"
```

And in the function on the parent window I execute my code

```
function myFunction() {
 if ((action == 'forward')) {
        window.historyControl+=1;
    } else {
        window.historyControl-=1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$('#iframe').ready(function(){...})`. The callback will execute when your iframe's DOM structure is ready, in contrast with `.load()` callback which executes only when images and such are loaded. Source: [jQuery - What are differences between $(document).ready and $(window).load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8396407/jquery-what-are-differences-between-document-ready-and-window-load)

Comment: Thanks, but it just works the first time the main page is loaded. But after the user clicks a links inside the iframe it doesn't capture the changed contents.