# Windows onload event not working with custom javascript structure

Tags: javascript, jquery

My problem is that the jQuery `load` event is not working with my custom Javascript structure. I have tried many solutions to solve this problem but I failed.

```js
var Init_Template = (function($) {
  "use strict";

  return {
    init: function() {
      this.plugins();
      this.menus();
    },
    plugins: function() {
      // Codes
    },
    menus: function() {
      $(window).on("load", function(e) {
        alert();
      });
    }
  };
})(jQuery);

// Load when ready
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  function System_Init() {
    Init_Template.init();
  }

  if (window.self === window.top) {
    System_Init();
  } else {
    setTimeout(System_Init);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Isn't the load event the same as jquery's ready function?

Comment: Your code works fine, although note that it won't in the snippet as the `window.self === window.top` condition fails.

Comment: @Kognise no, they are [slightly different.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8396407/jquery-what-are-differences-between-document-ready-and-window-load)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Ah ok. thanks. Any chance the window load event and the ready event are racing in some way?

Comment: No. `document.ready` will always fire first.

Comment: Got it. Sorry, my brain isn't working :D

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Please take a look at 'menus' function there's an alert must be run after the page is loaded but that does not happen.

Comment: I've seen it. It appears when you comment out the `window.self === window.top` condition: https://jsfiddle.net/0sn9cy81/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have do that but the alert still not run :(

Comment: Then you need to debug why that condition is not working for you. The structure of your JS is not the problem.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan in the demo link that you have added the alert still not run https://jsfiddle.net/0sn9cy81/ but if we do something like this https://jsfiddle.net/vc86u4bg/ it's working without any issues.

Comment: setTimeout causes the code to run after the window.onload has fired. Remove the setTimeout call and call it directly and see it fire....

Comment: @epascarello Same thing please check my previous comment to understand more.

Comment: I understand fine.... setTimeout causes it to load after the window load is triggered.... nothing you can do about it... Makes no sense really why you are doing this pattern with the timeout.

Comment: @epascarello i understand you and i have do what you say but the alert still not run please check this demo https://jsfiddle.net/a3w0xn2u/

Comment: I get an alert... maybe your pop up blocker is blocking it.

Comment: @epascarello I don't use any blocker and i have tried with another browser, But if you sure that the alert run in this link jsfiddle.net/a3w0xn2u so thank you for your time I will try to found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You will want that script with the jquery loading BEFORE you execute your javascript and jquery code so move the script tag above your code. I believe this will solve your issue for you.