# Is it possible to control the order in which HTML Razor components render?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, razor

I'm trying to render one of my pages, and I have an `Html.RenderAction()` call at the top of the div I'd like to display. I'd like to call one of my js initializer methods in `document.ready()` from inside the page that is displayed via my RenderAction call, but it seems to be triggering `document.ready()` before the html in the page after the `Html.RenderAction()` call.

Because of this, the init function is checking data from a kendo element that hasn't loaded since it's being called before JQuery finishes up, and only sees the inputs that should be kendo inputs as default html `<input>` elements.

In other words, is there a way to delay the loading / call of RenderAction until the page its inside of loads? Or should I just use some ugly CSS to keep the section I need at the top of my div? Very basic summary of my code below:

```
<html>
...
<div>
  @Html.RenderAction("File that calls init() method")
  <...rest of page that I need to load first, including kendo text boxes/>
</div>

</html>
```

File that calls init() method

```
<div>
...
</div>
<script src="...">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    myJs.init(params)
  }
</script>
```

---

---

Now that I've gone to implement the answer below elsewhere, I've realized that when switching from `document.ready` to `window.on('load',...)`, it's now broken another view that works similarly, but instead the `@Html.RenderAction` call is on the bottom:

```
...
<div>
  <>page including kendo inputs</>
  @Html.RenderAction("different file that calls same init() method")
</div>

</html>
```

Basically, `document.ready` works for me if the razor is before the kendo, but not the other way around - and `window.on('load',function(){...})` works for the opposite.

---

**UPDATE:** I ended up having to just rearrange my page after a lot of trial and error looking for a fix for this - seems like there's no easy way around the order in which the razor loads on CSHTML pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having to just rearrange my page after a lot of trial and error looking for a fix for this - seems like there's no easy way around the order in which the razor loads on CSHTML pages.

Answer (score 1):

This might work, try using $(window).load(function() instead of $(document).ready(function()

```
<div>
...
</div>
<script src="...">
  $(window).load(function() {
    myJs.init(params)
  }
</script>
```

From the below link: "executes when complete page is fully loaded, including all frames, objects and images"

[jQuery - What are differences between $(document).ready and $(window).load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8396407/jquery-what-are-differences-between-document-ready-and-window-load)

Comment: Yep! That worked, thanks. The only change I had to make to what was suggested in that link you posted was to change ```$(window).load(function(){...})``` to ```$(window).on('load', function(){...})``` due to an update later on in that answer: https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#breaking-change-load-unload-and-error-removed